# Disable textbox after typing in a value C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to disable a textbox after user has inserted a value. I have tried playing with the "KeyPress" property but the first digit I type in is also the "KeyPress", so it locks on the first character. Maybe I can get the textbox to lock after pressing Enter or using Tab. What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: Try to handle `TextChanged` event instead.

Comment: 'TextChanged' event also locks on the first character

Comment: what should happen when the user leaves the textbox but with out typing any value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to disable the box after the person leave it. (I assume that from your Enter/Tab option.) If so, look into the [`TextBox.LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

Though, the "Best" generally depends on the customer requirement, I would do the disabling act on the Lost Focus event.

```
 private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       textBox2.Enabled = false;
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use Leave event and in body assign Enabled to false;

Answer (score 0):

you can use the LostFocus event or the  ManipulationCompleted event handler